# Understanding the capacitors in an op amp circuit

Tags: capacitor, operational-amplifier, amplifier, decoupling-capacitor, probe

I am a computer programmer forced to make some circuits for a [Langmuir probe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langmuir_probe) our lab is making (the main task is programming the analytic software on the computer, but I have to make a basic amplifier circuit as well). Below is a circuit made by a colleague of mine for a similar problem that I'm basing my work on. I understand everything except for the capacitors. Are they for decoupling, or filtering, or what? Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 1uF capacitor forms a simple low-pass filter with th 4.7K to filter the PWM square wave from the microcontroller.

The 100nF cap in parallel with 4.7K does not do much- it prevents erosion of the op-amp phase margin due to input and stray capacitance on the inverting input.

Comment: Can you explain the second paragraph?

Comment: And how does the filter work?

Comment: Without the 100n, the 4.7K forms a low-pass filter with stray capacitance and input capacitance to ground, which delays the feedback signal. That could cause the op-amp to be less stable. You could short the 4.7K, but that would increase the DC error due to bias current. The principle is the same as the 1uF/4.7K which is an [low pass RC filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter) with a cutoff frequency of 33Hz. If the PWM frequency is **much** higher (say 10kHz) there won't be much ripple in the capacitor voltage (~1% p-p of output at midscale).

Comment: Should one always use that design when working with op amps?

Comment: No, there are many possible configurations. This kind of filter is about the simplest. If you need lower ripple for a given response time, a better filter would be necessary (eg, the much-maligned Sallen-Key type might be used).